# Creating a Select from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, select, multidimensional-array

So I have an array from a database query, it's something like this:

Array (

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => Name1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => Name2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => Name3
    )
```

I'm trying to create a Select from that (it has +50 arrays, not only 2) and I tried doing this:

```html
<select name="client" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="" disabled selected>--client--</option>
                <?php
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($idnameCli); $i++) { 
                        echo "<option value='$idnameCli[$i][1]'>$idnameCli[$i][0] $idnomCli[$i][1] </option>";
                    }
                ?>
</select>
```

Problem is it's not taking the second [ ] so it's showing "Array[0]Array[1]" instead of "3Name2".
I tried a couple things like creating variables:

$id = "0"; // $id = "[0]";

Still not working.

How should I call an Array in an Array in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because you've to use quotes or escape those. You can do it simply using [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php),

```
<select name="client" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="" disabled selected>--client--</option>
                <?php
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($idnameCli); $i++) { 
                        echo "<option value='".$idnameCli[$i][1]."'>". implode('',$idnameCli[$i]) ."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
</select>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/TATGZ

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, didn't knew implode exist that makes it much cleaner! 
I'm kinda new to php and I still mess up with the quotes.
Thank you!

Comment: @TraaZ glad it helps you somehow, Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome on Stackoverflow,

I had lot of difficulty to read your question so i hope i've understood what you want.

```
<select>
<?php for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($prova); $i++){
    echo "<option value=\"".$arr[$i][0]."\">".$arr[$i][0]."-".$arr[$i][1]."</option> ";
} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I never used "\" in an echo call I'm not sure what it does but it does work!

Comment: In this case "\" considers the next character as part of the string instead of a delimiter. Else the " would end the string.

Answer (score 0):

See [manual : String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

When you write :

```
echo "<option value='$idnameCli[$i][1]'> ...
```

It's like you want to set a value for that option which is the string `'$idnameCli[$i][1]'` ; if you wanted the value to be "johnny" you would write `"<option value='johnny'>`

In PHP you concatenate strings and variables with "." like :

```
"<option value='" . $idnameCli[$i][1] . "'> ...
```

And also in your case two variables next to each other (here  with a space between them) :

```
echo "<option value='" . $idnameCli[$i][1] . "'>" . $idnameCli[$i][0] . " " . $idnomCli[$i][1] . "</option>";
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful ^^